# Why is the dropbox daemon running immediately whenever I open a new terminal window?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, dropbox, virtual-console

Every time I open a new terminal window, the dropbox daemon starts. There is nothing in my .bashrc to start this, nor is `Start Dropbox at system startup` enabled. Why is this happening?

```bsh
dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-XPAN6W
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.6.7
dropbox: setting program path '/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92'dropbox: setting python path '/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92:/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92/python-packages-36.zip'
user@host:~$ dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92
.... (etc, until I hit ^C)
```

The line later that shows the daemon being killed

```bsh
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/steve/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-68.3.92/PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
^C
steve@xpsubu-bb:~$ ^C
[1]+  Interrupt               ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

`grep` does not show anything in `~/.bashrc`... how did dropbox decide to start each terminal?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I wasn't looking into the initialization of bash enough; there was a malformed line in `~/.bash_alias` which called the dropbox daemon, instead of setting an alias.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Should have been...

```
alias start_dropbox='~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd'
```